# Xna timer++ in object.update()

Tags: c#, xna

English isn't my natal language, so please, excuse me in advance.

Because of computers performances, should i use gametime on timer?

like, replacing this

```
float timer = 0;

Update()
{
...code...
timer++;
...code...
}
```

by

```
float timer = 0;

Update()
{
...code...
timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
...code...
}
```

I am a little bit confused about it.
I know that gametime is the time to execute 1 loop (=1 frame)
So, to calculate the Fps = (1000 / gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;)

But i don't really know when to use the gametime in my code :s

if someone can help me about it...

It's strange, i didn't find a lot of websites which talked about GameTime. I thought it's basic ! =x

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GameTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime_members.aspx) class contains information about different time values that you can use to do things inside your game.

For example, the current position (say only X) of a sprite moving at a constant speed is given by

> totalTimeInMilliSecondsSinceStartOfGame * speed

, where *speed* is some factor. Now this sprite will move at the same speed irrespective of what machine you run this code on (framerate).

This is the real purpose of the GameTime class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes sorry, i knew that, i already use it to move sprites. The thing is, GameTime isn't only used on moving a Sprite right ? Should i use GameTime on "every calculations" ? =x (and are you agree with **timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;** ?)

Comment: Yes, I agree. You need to keep a running counter for current time. This is what I do (https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti/blob/master/Samples/Quake3Shader/Game.cs). See my Update function.

Comment: Thx for your answers, your link is interesting, i'll recheck it later. I don't know if i'll find an answer in it, but thx a lot anyway !